# discord.js voice channels no sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, voice-recognition

I'm working on a discord.js v13 bot that joins a voice channel then listen for user then transfer the voice to text then transfer the text to voice then send it back to the voice channel

When I join the voice channel with the bot the bot doesn't send voice I think it's a problem with my code so can someone solve it or tell me the problem in the code

Here's the code :

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { VoiceConnectionStatus, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { getAudioUrl } = require('google-tts-api');
const Transcriber = require("discord-speech-to-text");
const transcriber = new Transcriber("api key");
const DiscordTTS = require("discord-tts");
const axios = require('axios');
//const AssemblyAI = require('assemblyai_nodejs');

const client = new Client({
    intents:[
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
    ]
});

//const assemblyClient = new AssemblyAI("49457b83b09243b494eccd");

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith('!listen')) return;

  // Join the voice channel of the user who sent the command
  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel) return message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
  const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: voiceChannel.id,
    guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    selfDeaf: false,
  selfMute: false,
  });

  const audioStream = connection.receiver.subscribe(message.author.id, { mode: 'pcm' });

  const audioChunks = [];

  audioStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    audioChunks.push(chunk);
  });

  audioStream.on('end', async () => {
    const audioBuffer = Buffer.concat(audioChunks);
    
    try {
      // Send audio buffer to AssemblyAI for transcription
      
  transcriber.listen(audioBuffer).then((data) => {
    if (!data.transcript.text) return;
    let texter = data.transcript.text;
    let userer = data.user;
  })

      const transcript = response.text;
      
      // Translate text to desired language using Google Translate API
      const translationResponse = await axios.get(`https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=fr&dt=t&q=${encodeURI(texter)}`);
      const translatedText = translationResponse.data[0][0][0];

      // Convert translated text to speech using AssemblyAI
      const audioURL = getAudioUrl(texter, {
      lang: 'en',
      slow: false,
      host: 'https://translate.google.com',
      timeout: 10000,
    });
const resource = DiscordTTS.getVoiceStream("Hello world!");
      // Create audio player and resource
      const player = createAudioPlayer();
   //   const resource = createAudioResource(audioURL);
      player.play(resource);

      // Play the speech in the voice channel
      connection.subscribe(player);
      //player.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Destroyed, () => {
   //     connection.destroy();
//      });
    } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
    }
//  });

  // Stop audio stream after 5 seconds
//  setTimeout(() => {
  //  audioStream.destroy();
//  }, 5000);
  
})});
client.login('token');
```